# How to fill missing value with KNN method for binary variables in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-mining, missing-data, knn

I have a dataset that has a number of numeric variables. I want to use the KNN  method to fill in the missing value. The following code does not fill in the missing value correctly because some of the filled values are out of range. For example I have binary variable but it fills them with a floating number.

As you can see in the tables below, I get  0.66 instead of 1.

Please advise why the code is wrong.

```
 df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
   
    from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
    imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=3)
    df = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(df),columns = df.columns)
```

Data set:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 |
| NAN | 0 |
| NAN | NAN |
| 1 | 1 |

Result:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0.66 |
| 1 | 1 |

Comment: "The following code...". Where is that?

Comment: @kinshukdua Sorry I added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns 2 is basically contain two values ( 0 and 1 ).It is not a numerical feature ,it is categorical feature So you can use the mode to fill the missing value in column 2

Comment: That means, KNN does not respond to ordinal and nominal variables?

Comment: It will works IF you take the n_neighbors=2